# How to calculate organisation business hours?

Tags: businesshours

I need to store the organization business hours value in a field .. Is it possible to store that in a formula field ? If not , by any chance can we get the organization business hours through coding or something ?
In my org , there are 33  countries and each country has different org business hours(monday - sunday)...
Please help me out !! thanks in advance !!!

Comment: I did not proceed anything. I am totally screwed!!!

Comment: But have you configured your business hours already?

Comment: What object are you referring to? Are you trying to determine which BusinessHours are relevant to a certain user/account/contact? If so, it would be possible to store the name or id of the appropriate BusinessHours in a formula field.

Answer (score 1):

You can get organization business hours using Apex code. Salesforce has object named "BusinessHours" which has details of business hours from Monday-Sunday.

You can write your logic around this object and show desired results.

Object Reference: [BusinessHours](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_businesshours.htm)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a functionality to later find out difference between date fields which provide the business hours. You can create formula field to calculate that.

In the [Common Date Formulas](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=formula_examples_dates.htm) following section might be helpful for you.

- Finding the Number of Business Hours Between Two Date/Times

You can tweak the formula little bit as per the need.

Thank You.